# django 'admin' is not a registered namespace in pybbm-forum app on subdomain

Tags: django, subdomain, forum

I have django 1.10.7, python2.7, installed django-hosts, [pybbm](https://github.com/hovel/pybbm) app.
Pybbm forum on subdomain forum.example.com.
When i'l trying open topic on url forum.example.com/topic/1/, that already have created, i get error.

```
NoReverseMatch at /topic/1/
u'admin' is not a registered namespace
```

my hosts.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django_hosts import patterns, host
from django.conf import settings
host_patterns = patterns('',
host(r'example.com', settings.ROOT_URLCONF, name='www'),
host(r'forum', 'forums.urls', name='forum'),
)
```

my forums/urls.py, where i included pybb urls

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('pybb.urls', namespace='pybb')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Can you help how to better configure pybbm forum app with my django project on subdomain?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have no admin url in your 'forums/urls.py' and the template that renders '/topic/1/' has some django url link pointing to admin routes (e.g. `<a href="{% url 'admin:foo' %}">Foo</a>`) that doesn't even exist. Can you show the template code?

Comment: it's template topic.html


`{% if perms.pybb.change_topic and user.is_staff %}
            <a href="{% url 'admin:pybb_topic_change' topic.id %}">{% trans 'Admin' %}</a> /
                        {% endif %}`

Comment: `'admin:pybb_topic_change'` should probably be changed to something like `'pybb:pybb_topic_change'` since the only namespace registered in your urls.py is 'pybb'